# Why the set $ \{ \frac{1}{n} \} \cup\{ 0\}$ is not locally analytic

Tags: analytic-geometry

In 0 all neighboor have infinite points. intuitively it seems that it can not be locally analytical because infinite equations are needed. but why is not it?.

Comment: If you have a finite set of analytical functiuons such that your set is equal to the zeros of these functions then atleast one function must have infinitely many zeros. Apply the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem).